# Group Null Records using a Window Function in SQL

Tags: sql, view, group-by

Given the following data:

```
declare @temp table(id int identity primary key, val nvarchar)

insert into @temp values (NULL)
insert into @temp values (NULL)
insert into @temp values ('A')
insert into @temp values (NULL)
insert into @temp values (NULL)
insert into @temp values ('B')
insert into @temp values ('C')
insert into @temp values (NULL)
insert into @temp values (NULL)
insert into @temp values ('A')
insert into @temp values (NULL)
insert into @temp values (NULL)
```

I'm trying to get the output below. The records need to be grouped so that with each new value the group number increases by one. The values themselves do not matter - if there is any value other than NULL a new group ID is added. Records have to be ordered by Id.

```
Id Val  Group
-- ---  -----
1  NULL 1
2  NULL 1
3  A    2
4  NULL 2
5  NULL 2
6  B    3
7  C    4
8  NULL 4
9  NULL 4
10 A    5
11 NULL 5
```

I was hoping using PARTITION BY would be the solution, but I can't seem to get this working (if indeed it is possible/the right approach. I have a solution using a LOOP but I'd rather use a query. I'm using SQL Server 2008. Thanks for any suggestions.

```
select id, val, row_number() over (partition by X order by id) from @temp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
select t.id, t.val, DENSE_RANK() over (order by prevval) as grouping
from (select *,
             (select top 1 id from @temp t2 where t2.val is not null and t2.id <= t.id order by id desc
             ) as prevval
      from @temp t
     ) t
```

This uses a correlated subquery to get the largest id less than or equal to the given value where the `val` is not null (if any).  It then dense ranks these by the id, to get a sequential grouping.

If you are using SQL Server 2012, then there is a related approach, without the subquery:

```
select t.id, t.val, DENSE_RANK() over (order by prevval) as grouping
from (select *,
             max(case when val is not null then id end) over (order by id) as prevval
      from @temp t
     ) t
```

Comment: @geographika . . . Thank you for posting an interesting question, with working test code.